# Mid point with set square?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-constructions

> Is it possible to construct the midpoint of a segment in the hyperbolic plane 
>   using the *set square* only?

With the *set square* one can

- draw the line through the given two points and
- drop the perpendicular from the given point to the given line.

---

The following construction produce the point $X'$ which is centrally symmetric to the point $X$ with respect to point $O$.

1. Draw line $(OX)$ and let $m$ be the line perpendicular to $(OX)$ through $O$.
2. Draw yet two perpendicular lines $l$ and $l'$ through $O$.
3. Find the foot point $Y$ of $X$ on $l$.
4. Draw the line through $Y$ perpendicular to $m$ and let $Z$ be its intersection with $l'$.
5. Finally, $X'$ is the footpoint of $Z$ on $l$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I realized that the answer is NO.

Let us think of hyperbolic plane as about subset of projective plane for $\mathbb R^{2,1}$.

Note that in this model, the set square tool is the same as hyperbolic-cross-product tool;
i.e. for any two vectors $u$ and $v$ 
you can construct the vector 
$$w=J(u\times v),$$
where
$$ J\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\-z\end{pmatrix}$$

If the end points of the segment are given by rational vectors then so are all the hyperbolic-cross-products. 
On the other hand, it is easy to construct two rational vectors such that their hyperbolic bisector goes in an irrational directin. 
Hence the result follows.

---

In **spherical geometry**, the same question has also answer NO.
It is easier to visualize since in spherical geometry the *set square tool* is equivalent to the *cross-product tool*.

Answer (score 3):

I can do it if I am allowed to cheat - in axiom one for the set square (which is the axiom for the straight-edge) I'll allow one of the points to be ideal: that is, on the Gromov boundary of $H^2$.  Also, I assume that the set square produces infinite geodesic rays.  In particular, this means, in the second axiom, that the given point can be on the given line.

Suppose the segment $[x,y]$ is given.  Draw the geodesic ray $P$, based at $x$ and perpendicular to $[x,y]$.  Do the same at $y$ to get the ray $Q$, on the same side of $[x,y]$.  Connect the ideal endpoint of $P$ to $y$ and the ideal endpoint of $Q$ to $x$.  These new rays cross at $z$.  Drop a perpendicular from $z$ to $[x,y]$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another construction that works in the Euclidean plane.  Suppose we want the midpoint of $A$ and $B$.  Take any $C$ between $A$ and $B$, and draw some $D$ off of $\overline{AB}$ such that $\overline{CD}$ and ${AB}$ are perpendicular.   You can construct a line parallel to $\overline{AD}$ that goes through $B$ by drawing a perpendicular to $\overline{AD}$ and then another perpendicular to that new line.  You can also draw a parallel to $\overline{BD}$ through $A$.  These two parallels intersect at $E$.  Then $ADBE$ forms a parallelogram, and you can intersect the diagonals to find the midpoint $F$ of $AB$.

Now, in the hyperbolic plane, the parallel you find isn't unique, so there are multiple ways to do this same construction.  And when you do, $F$ is not going to be a midpoint.  However, $F$ will be closer to the midpoint than $C$ (I believe).  Hence, repeating the construction, you could construct maybe construct a sequence of points that converge to the midpoint.  Obviously that sort of thing isn't allowed in a construction, but it's at least going in the right direction =).